# htaccess add index.php to the route with more paths after it

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am building a REST using framework.
Normally I can call my web services by going to this route

> https://www.domainname.com/webservices/index.php/something/else/here

Now I want to be able to hide index.php but still call the same route like this

> https://www.domainname.com/webservices/something/else/here

Currently I am able to get 200-OK from only going up to webservices/

using the following htaccess rewrite:

> RewriteRule ^webservices/(.*)/$ webservices/index.php/$1 [R,L]

however, everything after the webservices/ will give me a 404 not found

here is an example.

- webservices/           ---200-OK (I see the page of webservices/index.php
- webservices/something  ---404 not found
- webservices/some/thing ---404 not found

I guess the biggest question is how do I add the paths after I add the index.php (the level of paths should be dynamic)

P.S. I don't want to display index.php in the URL at all

Comment: Your current rule requires trailing slash.

Comment: can you please elaborate more, I am very new at htaccess

Comment: try `^webservices/(.*)$` instead of `^webservices/(.*)/$`

Comment: that will result in webservices/ going into an infinite loop of redirect index.php(.*)$